# Public Enumeration with only string values

Tags: c#, enumeration

I'm always confused which kind of enumeration I should use. A hashtable, an enum, a struct a dictionary, an array (how oldschool), static strings...

Instead of using strings in my code I want to use a beautiful enum like so:

```
public enum MyConfigs
{
    Configuration1,
    Configuration2
}
```

Problem is that I don't always want to convert my enum `toString()` as I'm not interested in the index representation of the `enum`.

**What is the best way to represent a public enumeration of string based values?**
In the end I would love to end up with using `MyConfigs.Configuration1` where needed in my code.

Comment: As per your problem you dont really need a hastable nor KeyValuePair DS. And would you tell us what type is Configuration1, Configuration2, etc.? And whats the purpose of you doing it. basically add more info, plz.

Comment: Really just strings. In the end they'll show up in the logs as "This error came from `Configuration1`".

Comment: Enum would be a best choice, but again every time you need to convert or boxing should happen, thus degrading performance. So go as per Marc suggested.

Comment: Do you need to pass these values as parameters into methods? If so you might want to look at the type-safe enum pattern. This would allow you to pass your 'enumerated' strings around like this: `private void Foo(StringEnum value){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class MyConfigs
{
    public const string Configuration1 = "foo",
                        Configuration2 = "bar"
}
```

This is then pretty-much identical to how enums are implemented (ignoring the whole "it must be an integer" thing).

Comment: Isn't using a class rather ugly? What are all those nice enumeration forms for then? ;-)

Comment: IMO, using enums for string values would be uglier (not to mention unconventional) with ToString()s all over the place. Don't be afraid of a sprinkle of micro-classes in your project, I say.

Comment: @moontear how is it ugly? it is, ultimately, not much different to defining an enum.

Comment: Seeing the other ideas this is not ugly. I just thought it was ugly because I define a full class for this - but as Ishmaeel says it might be fine to have a micro-class here and there.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer defining "grouped" constants as static members of a dummy static class, like so:

```
public static class FieldNames
{
    public const string BRANCH_CODE = "_frsBranchCode";
    public const string BATCH_ID = "_frsBatchId";
    public const string OFFICE_TYPE = "_frsOfficeType";
}
```

But of course they are not "enumerable" directly, so you can't foreach over them unless you provide a static array too:

```
public static string[] AllFieldNames
{
    get
    {
        return new string[]
        {
            FieldNames.BRANCH_CODE,
            FieldNames.BATCH_ID,
            FieldNames.OFFICE_TYPE
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type-safe enum pattern?

```
public class StringEnum
{
    #region Enum Values

    public static readonly StringEnum ValueOne = new StringEnum("Value One");
    public static readonly StringEnum ValueTwo = new StringEnum("Value Two");

    #endregion

    #region Enum Functionality

    public readonly string Value;

    private StringEnum(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can use this like:

```
private void Foo(StringEnum enumVal)
{
  return "String value: " + enumVal;
}
```

If you never need to pass these values around in a type-safe manner to methods etc. then it is probably best to just stick with a constants file.